# How can I establish socket connection between Python processes (for inter-process communication) while using a Flask webserver

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-multiprocessing, python-sockets

I'm relatively new to Python and have been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a python script whose sole purpose is to control a piece of hardware. This controller script's main function runs in a continuous loop and each iteration of the loop may send messages to the hardware. The script also provides a mechanism for receiving inputs from an external source via the multiprocessing library's `Listener` socket class.

In a separate python script (i.e. running in a separate process) I am running a flask server which has routes defined to receive messages and forward them to the controller process described above. I am using the multiprocessing library's `Client` socket class for sending messages.

The problem I'm encountering is once I start the flask server I can't seem to establish a socket connection with the controller script. The flask process hangs when I attempt to do so.

Below is a code sample illustrating my setup. Note the use of threading in each script (which may also not be correct):

#### controller.py

```
class HardwareControllerThread(threading.Thread)
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def update(self, value):
      # Do something with `value` here

if __name__ == "__main__":
  thread = HardwareControllerThread()
  thread.start()

  address = ("localhost", 6000)
  listener = Listener(address)
  connection = listener.accept()

  while True:
    try:
      msg = connection.recv()

      if msg == "close":
        connection.close()
        thread.join()
      else:
        thread.update(msg)
    except EOFError:
      continue

  listener.close()
```

#### server.py

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def update():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=sendMessage, args=("message to send",))
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    return flask.Response(status=200)


def sendMessage(message):
    client = Client(("localhost", 6000))
    print("connected to client")  # never get to this line
    colorDriverClient.send(message)
    colorDriverClient.close()

app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: @noxdafox seems to have some insights here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169609/2836621 and may be able to comment.